# Python: Iterative subdirectory line count

Tags: python, regex, count, subdirectory, os.walk

I'm attempting to count the number of lines in two separate directories that are formatted differently and compare the results. The text files needed are all within a single directory in the the first dir, but the second one has subdirectories that I need to iterate through, save the name of, and then pull and count all txt files that begin with the name.

At the moment, I'm having trouble comparing the subdirectory name with the txt files that begin with it. My traceback is as follows:

```
be29X1(149)% ./SeriesCount.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SeriesCount.py", line 23, in <module>
    for fn in files('subdir_name*.txt'):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I don't need to permanently save the subdirectory name, since all I care about is storing the txt file names and their counts to a dict. For example, if the directory name is "regprices", I want to pull out the line counts for all text files within the directory that begin with "regprices". Code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import copy
import os
import sys
import glob
import dircmp

#set dicts 
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
final_dict = {}

#parses through directory 1, counts lines, saves to a dict
for fn in glob.glob('/data/*.txt'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        dict1[fn] = [1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')]

#parses through subdirectories in directory 2, counts lines, saves to a dict
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/docs/prod/count/'):
    subdir_name = os.getcwd()
    for fn in files('subdir_name*.txt'):
        dict2[fn] = [1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')]

#compare dicts, overwrite counts from dict1 with dict2, save to final dict

save final dictionary with key/val pairs to a csv
with open('seriescount.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, final_dict) 
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow({k:sum(v) for k, v in final_dict.items()})
```

Bonus points if you can help with syntax comparing the two dictionaries, overwriting the counts from dir2 to dir1, and saving them to final_dict

Answer (score 0):

Example is all over the place with differently named variables. Definitely not a working example. It's hard to work out what you're trying to achieve.

Not sure how you're trying to compare the dictionary keys based on filename. Here's an attempt at guessing what you're trying to achieve.

```
import glob
import os


def count_lines(filename):
  with open(filename,'r') as f:
    count = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and line[0] != '#')
  return count

def directory1_count(path='/data/*.txt'):
  counts = {}
  for filepath in glob.glob(path):
    directory, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    counts[name] = count_lines(filepath)
  return counts

def directory2_count(path='/docs/prod/count/'):
  counts = {}
  for directory, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    _, subdir = os.path.split(directory)
    for filename in [x for x in files if x.startswith(subdir) and x.endswith('.txt')]:
      name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
      filepath = os.path.join(directory,filename)
      counts[name] = count_lines(filepath)
  return counts

counts = directory1_count()
counts.update(directory2_count())
```

Comment: changed diff named vars

Comment: I've tried defining the count as a separate method as well, but your line: count = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and line[0] != '#')  returns a syntax error (I believe it's because it doesn't allow you to sum and count in the same line). Any ideas about how to go about this?

Comment: As for comparing the two directories, I'm simply planning on traversing through the filenames and, if there are duplicate filenames, updating the file count to the directory 2 count instead of the directory 1 count

Comment: @briahnah: what was the syntax error, what version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm just getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I'm running Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

Comment: @briahnah I've just copied this code and run it: worked with no syntax errors in python 2.7. Suggest you double check.